# knockout.js (2.2.0) How to get data from Json Array using dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/ptmwr/)** 
I'm facing the following problem:
I have an json array:

```
self.customExportFileArray = ko.observableArray([
      {
        "IncludeInExportConversionTypesSelectList" :
          [
            {
              "ConversionGroupID" : 1,
              "Title" : "Quote Start - Auto"
            },
            {
              "ConversionGroupID" : 2,
              "Title" : "Quote Finish - Auto"
            },
            {
              "ConversionGroupID" : 5,
              "Title" : "Sales Data"
            }
          ],
        "ChooseFromConversionTypesSelectList" : [],
        "FileName" : "Template1",
        "FileFormat" : "Excel",
        "FilterSettings" : true,
        "ComparisonMetrics" : false
      },
      {
        "IncludeInExportConversionTypesSelectList":
          [
            {
              "ConversionGroupID" : 1,
              "Title" : "Quote Start - Auto"
            },
            {
              "ConversionGroupID" : 5,
              "Title" : "Sales Data"
            }
          ],
        "ChooseFromConversionTypesSelectList":
          [
            {
              "ConversionGroupID" : 2,
              "Title" : "Quote Finish - Auto"
            }
          ],
        "FileName" : "Template2",
        "FileFormat" : "CSV",
        "FilterSettings" : false,
        "ComparisonMetrics" : true
      }
    ]);
}
```

And I have some HTML Code which contains one dropdown, text box, few radio-buttons and Two List controls. So, the point is: Dropdown should contain as many Items as `customExportFileArray` array's length, and Item name (optionsText) should be `FileName` property from array. (Looks like it work now). Next, If change the Item from dropdown, let's say `Template1` File Name textbox should be filled by FileName property from array (Template1), Excel radiobutton should be checked, Keep filter settings should be checked, Compatison Metrics should be unchecked and 'Conversion Types to Choose From' should contain a list of `IncludeInExportConversionTypesSelectList` array (Text = Title)

 
But if to see in my HTML Code I'm doing something wrong, but don't know what exactly. It doesn't load specific data by changing Item from dropdown, but I thought that I'm doing all in a right way.
Additional question: How to save changes for specific Item array (I mean, for example you changed the name, or changed checked radiobutton).

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/ptmwr/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be binding the value of the drop down to an observable property called something like 'SelectedTemplate' to store the selected value, then binding the changeable fields to the selected object:

```
<select data-bind="options: customExportFileArray, optionsText: function(item) { return item.FileName }, value: selectedTemplate">

<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedTemplate().FileName"/>

self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();
self.customExportFileArray = ko.observableArray([
      {
       ....
```

I have modified your jsfiddle as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/ptmwr/11/

As you can see, the values binding of the drop down now points at this new property, and I had to change the way the optionstext binds to work with the object as a value.

**EDIT:**

Also you are trying to bind a boolean to RadioButton's checked property, which they are not really designed for. If you want to bind to a boolean property then you should use checkbox control instead as this is either on or off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Roysvork!!! The last question to you and I will close current question. I've updated jsFiddle by your recommendation, but I can't understand why Filter Settings, Comparison Metrics and Include in Export List doesn't work at all [Here is the link to updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/ptmwr/12/). Thank you.

Comment: I'm just having a look... but to test my psychic powers have you got the brackets right? : )

Comment: Ahh no brackets look fine. Whats happening is that knockout doesn't know how to map from the boolean values to what you have defined as your values for the radio buttons. If you set values on those then hopefully that should work...

Comment: Sorry that was a red herring. I will update the answer with an Edit explaining.

Comment: Thank you Roysvork again for your help!!! Regarding Why List didn't display Items - it was an issue related to sortable, probably I've missed some library, anyway Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Yes sorry I have no experience with sortables : ) Something I should look into perhaps!